# MongooseJs: How to set a custom error message for required, unique index and enum failure

Tags: node.js

```
var userSchema = Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    match: /^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true
  },
  nickname: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  url: { type: String, trim: true, default: '' },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: [ 'admin', 'reader' ],
    default: 'reader'
  },
  about: { type: String, trim: true },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true }
});
```

I'd like to customize this with something more user friendly, But I don't know how to set a custom error message for required, unique index and enum failure. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can override the error message with the required option. If you need to customize the message in the schema, instead of at the point of the save, I'd think your best bet would be to write a custom validator, like this:

```
function createdValidator(created) {
  return (created !== undefined && created !== null);
}

....

new Schema({created: { type: Date, default: Date.now, validate: [createdValidator, "custom error message"] } });
```

**Update:**

According to the documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate), you can do multiple validations like this:

```
var multiple = [
  { validator: createdValidator, msg: "custom error message" },
  { validator: function(created){ return true;}, msg: "You'll never see me" }
];

new Schema({created: { type: Date, validate: multiple }});
```

Comment: How about multiple validates?

Comment: Yeah, there's some documentation on doing multiple validations, I'll update my answer so it can be formatted.